# Can sed regex simulate lookbehind and lookahead?

Tags: regex, sed, awk, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a sed script that will capture all "naked" URL's in a text file and replace them with `<a href=[URL]>[URL]</a>`. By "naked" I mean a URL that is not wrapped inside an anchor tag.

My initial thought was that I should match URL's that do not have a " or a > in front of them, and also do not have a < or a " after them. However, I am running into difficulty with expressing the concept of "do not have in front of or behind" because as far as I know sed does not have look-ahead or look-behind.

Sample Input:

```
[Beginning of File]http://foo.bar arbitrary text
http://test.com other text
<a href="http://foobar.com">http://foobar.com</a>
Nearing end of file!!! http://yahoo.com[End of File]
```

Sample Desired Output:

```
[Beginning of File]<a href="http://foo.bar">http://foo.bar</a> arbitrary text
<a href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a> other text
<a href="http://foo.bar">http://foo.bar</a>
Nearing end of file!!! <a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>[End of File]
```

Observe that the third line is unmodified, because it is already inside `<a href>`.
On the other hand, both the first and second lines are modified.
Finally, observe that all non-URL text is unmodified.

Ultimately, I am trying to do something like:

```
sed s/[^>"](http:\/\/[^\s]\+)/<a href="\1">\1<\/a>/g 2-7-2013
```

I began by verifying that the following will correctly match and remove a URL:

```
sed 's/http:\/\/[^\s]\+//g'
```

I then tried this, but it is not able to match URL's that start at the beginning of file / input:

```
sed 's/[^\>"]http:\/\/[^\s]\+//g'
```

Is there a way to work around this in sed, either by simulating lookbehind / lookahead, or explicitly matching beginning of file and end of file?

Comment: Why do you use `[^\>"]`?

Comment: I'm looking for a URL that is not preceded by quotation mark or a greater than sign.

Comment: Update your question to show some representative sample input and the expected output given that input - that's more important for us to see than what you have tried (though that's useful too).

Comment: @EdMorton, observe that the question has been updated with sample input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for any other text manipulation problems just use awk.

Check the definition I'm using in the BEGIN section below for a regexp that matches URLs. It works for your sample but I don't know if it captures all possible URL formats. Even if it doesn't though it may be adequate for your needs.

```
$ cat file
[Beginning of File]http://foo.bar arbitrary text
http://test.com other text
<a href="http://foobar.com">http://foobar.com</a>
Nearing end of file!!! http://yahoo.com[End of File]
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
[Beginning of File]<a href="http://foo.bar">http://foo.bar</a> arbitrary text
<a href="http://test.com">http://test.com</a> other text
<a href="http://foobar.com">http://foobar.com</a>
Nearing end of file!!! <a href="http://yahoo.com">http://yahoo.com</a>[End of File]
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ urlRe="http:[/][/][[:alnum:]._]+" }
{
    head = ""
    tail = $0
    while ( match(tail,urlRe) ) {
       url  = substr(tail,RSTART,RLENGTH)
       href = "href=\"" url "\""

       if (index(tail,href) == (RSTART - 6) ) {
          # this url is inside href="url" so skip processing it and the next url match.
          count = 2
       }

       if (! (count && count--)) {
          url = "<a " href ">" url "</a>"
       }

       head = head substr(tail,1,RSTART-1) url
       tail = substr(tail,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    }

    print head tail
}
```

Comment: In the url regex you use `_` as a valid host name character, shouldn't it be `-`?

Comment: As I say at the top of the answer `Check the definition I'm using in the BEGIN section below for a regexp that matches URLs. It works for your sample but I don't know if it captures all possible URL formats.`. I'm no URL syntax expert.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious problem with your command is

```
You did not escape the parenthesis "("
```

This is the weird thing about `sed` regex. It is different to Perl regex that many symbols are by default "literal". You have to escape them to "function". Try:

```
s/\([^>"]\?\)\(http:\/\/[^\s]\+\)/\1<a href="\2">\2<\/a>/g
```

Comment: As a clarification, I am trying to match URL's that do not have a " or a > in front of them.

Comment: The given solution will not match `http://google.com` at the beginning of file or beginning of input.

Comment: @merlin2011 I see what you mean. sed does not support look ahead/behind, I just edited. The question mark makes it optional

Comment: About the weird `\(`, an option is to use `sed -r` so that `(` doesn't need to be quoted. (I even have a `rsed` alias)

Comment: @texasbruce, when you make it optional, it now has the effect that it will match URL's inside `<a href=`, which is not the intent.

Comment: Incidentally, you can use the `-E` flag to use "modern" regex. Then you don't need to escape brackets.